# What does WS_EX_APPWINDOW do?

Tags: winapi

Either this is just a deprecated window style with no documentation, or I've made a flaw in searching for it.

My question is, what does this flag do? Is there a supported equivalent to it that I may need?

Advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`WS_EX_APPWINDOW` is an extended window style that is documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is most definitely not deprecated and is a fully supported and widely used style.

The documentation states that the style:

> Forces a top-level window onto the taskbar when the window is visible.

This is a relatively bland statement that undersells the purpose of this style. Normally the property that forces a top-level window onto the taskbar is the fact that the top-level window is unowned. Top-level owned windows do not, by default, appear on the taskbar. So, if for some reason you wish to put a top-level owned window onto the taskbar, then `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` is the solution.

Although there is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969325.aspx) that describes the rules for which windows appear in the taskbar, it is not as clear as it should be. [Raymond Chen's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/29/46371.aspx) describes it much more precisely:

> There are some basic rules on which windows go into the taskbar. In
>   short:
>
> - If the WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style is set, then it will show (when visible).
> - If the window is a top-level unowned window, then it will show (when visible).
> - Otherwise it doesn't show.

Comment: The rules described in Raymond Chen's article are incomplete. If the extended window style has `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` or `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` set, the window won't have a taskbar button, even if it is a visible, unowned top-level window.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Extended Window Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN it:

> Forces a top-level window onto the taskbar when the window is visible.

I don't see anywhere on the [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation that marks it as no longer supported.

Comment: I was looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908193.aspx, haven't realized until now that that was the Windows CE page.