# How to correctly have modeless form appear in taskbar

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-7, delphi-xe6, windows-95

I am trying to achieve the age-old Delphi dream of having a modeless form appear in the taskbar.

What is the *correct* way to have a modeless form appear in the taskbar?

---

## Research Effort

These are my attempts to solve the problem. There are a lot of things needed to make it behave **correctly** - simply having a button appear on the taskbar is not a solution. Having a Windows application behave correctly as a Windows application should is my goal.

For those who know me, and how deep my *"shows research effort"* goes, hang on because it will be wild ride down a rabbit hole.

The question is in the title, as well above the horizontal line above. Everything below only serves to show why some on the oft-repeated suggestions are incorrect.

### Windows only creates as taskbar button for unowned windows

Initially i have my *"Main Form"*, from that i show this other modeless form:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if frmModeless = nil then
        Application.CreateForm(TfrmModeless, frmModeless);

    frmModeless.Show;
end;
```

This correctly shows the new form, but no new button appears on the taskbar:

[image]

The reason no taskbar button is created is because that is by design. [Windows will only show a taskbar button for a window that ***"unowned"***](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/29/46371.aspx). This modeless Delphi form is most definitely *owned*. In my case it is owned by the `Application.Handle`:

[image]

My project's name is `ModelessFormFail.dpr`, which is the origin of the Windows class name `Modelessformfail` associated with the owner.

Fortunately there is a way to *force* Windows to create a taskbar button for a window, even though the window is owned:

### Just use `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`

The MSDN documentation of [`WS_EX_APPWINDOW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says it:

> **WS_EX_APPWINDOW** `0x00040000L` Forces a top-level window onto the taskbar when the window is visible.

It also a [well-known Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204397/what-does-ws-ex-appwindow-do) trick to override `CreateParams` and manually add the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style:

```
procedure TfrmModeless.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
    inherited;

    Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW; //force owned window to appear in taskbar
end;
```

When we run this, the newly created modeless form *does* indeed get its own taskbar button:

[image]

And we're done? No, because it doesn't behave correctly.

If the user clicks on the **frmMain** taskbar button, that window is not brought forward. Instead the other form (**frmModeless**) is brought forward:

[image]

This makes sense once you understand the Windows concept of *ownership*. Windows will, by design, bring any child *owned* forms forward. It was the entire purpose of ownership - to keep owned forms on top of their owners.

### Make the form actually unowned

The solution, [as some of you know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502820/my-detail-form-is-hidden-behind-main-form-when-calling-the-tsavedialog) is not to fight against the  taskbar heuristics and windows. If i want the form to be unowned, make it unowned.

This is (fairly) simple. In `CreateParam` force the owner windows to be `null`:

```
procedure TfrmModeless.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
    inherited;

    //Doesn't work, because the form is still owned
//  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW; //force owned windows to appear in taskbar

    //Make the form actually unonwed; it's what we want
    Params.WndParent := 0; //unowned. Unowned windows naturally appear on the taskbar.
          //There may be a way to simulate this with PopupParent and PopupMode.
end;
```

As an aside, i wanted to investigate is there was a way to use the [`PopupMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.PopupMode) and [`PopupParent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.PopupParent) properties to make a window unowned. I ***swear*** i read a comment (from you David) somewhere on SO saying that if you passed `Self` as the `PopupParent`, e.g.:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if frmModeless = nil then
    begin
        Application.CreateForm(TfrmModeless, frmModeless);
        frmModeless.PopupParent := frmModeless; //The super-secret way to say "unowned"? I swear David Heffernan mentioned it somewhere on SO, but be damned if i can find it now.
        frmModeless.PopupMode := pmExplicit; //happens automatically when you set a PopupParent, but you get the idea
    end;

    frmModeless.Show;
end;
```

it was supposed to be the super-secret way to indicate to Delphi that you want to form to have *"no owner"*. But i cannot find the comment anywhere on now. Unfortunately, no combination of `PopupParent` and `PopupMode` cause a form to *actually* be un-owned:

- PopupMode: **pmNone**

  - Owner hwnd: `Application.Handle/Application.MainForm.Handle`
- PopupMode: **pmAuto**

  - Owner hwnd: `Screen.ActiveForm.Handle`
- PopupMode: **pmExplicit**

  - PopupParent: **nil**

    - Owner hwnd: `Application.MainForm.Handle`
  - PopupParent: `AForm`

    - Owner hwnd: `AForm.Handle`
  - PopupParent: *Self*

    - Owner hwnd: `Application.MainForm.Handle`

Nothing i could do could cause the form to actually have *no* owner (each time checking with Spy++).

Setting the `WndParent` manually during [`CreateParams`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CreateParams):

- **does** make the form unowned
- it **does** have a taskbar button
- and both taskbar buttons **do**behave correctly:

[image]

And we're done, right? I thought so. I changed everything to use this new technique.

Except there are problems with my fix that seem to cause other problems - Delphi didn't like me changing to ownership of a form.

### Hint Windows

One of the controls on my modeless window has a tooltop:

[image]

The problem is that when this tooltip window appears, it causes the other form (**frmMain**, the modal one) to come forward. It doesn't gain activation focus; but it does now obscure the form i was look at:

[image]

The reason is probably logical. The Delphi **HintWindow** is probably owned either by `Application.Handle` or `Application.MainForm.Handle`, rather than being owned by the form that it should be owned by:

[image]

I would have considered this a bug on Delphi's part; using the wrong owner.

### Diversion to see the actual app layout

Now it's important that i take a moment to show that my application isn't a main form and a modeless form:

[image]

It's actually:

- a login screen (a sacrificial main form that gets hidden)
- a main screen
- a modal control panel
- that shows the modeless form

[image]

Even with the reality of the application layout, everything except for hint window ownership works. There are two taskbar buttons, and clicking them brings the proper form forward:

[image]

But we still have the problem of the HintWindow ownership bringing the wrong form forward:

[image]

## ShowMainFormOnTaskbar

It was when i was attempting to create a minimal application to reproduce the problem when i realize i couldn't. There was something different:

- between my Delphi 5 application ported to XE6
- a new application created in XE6

After [comparing](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) everything, i finally traced it down to the fact that new applications in XE6 add the **`MainFormOnTaskbar := True`** by default in any new project (presumably to not break existing applications):

```
program ModelessFormFail;
//...
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmSacrificialMain, frmSacrificialMain);
  //Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

When i added this option, then the appearance of the tooltip didn't bring the wrong form forward!:

[image]

Success! Except, people who know what's coming [know what's coming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441787/how-can-i-start-delphi-application-with-the-hidden-main-form). My *"sacrificial"* main login form shows the "real" main form, hiding itself:

```
procedure TfrmSacrificialMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    frmMain: TfrmMain;
begin
    frmMain := TfrmMain.Create(Application);
    Self.Hide;
    try
        frmMain.ShowModal;
    finally
        Self.Show;
    end;
end;
```

When that happens, and i *"login"*, my taskbar icon disappers entirely:

[image]

This happens because:

- the un-owned sacrificial main form is not invisible: so the button goes with it
- the real main form is **owned** so it does not get a toolbar button

### Use WS_APP_APPWINDOW

Now we have the opportunity to use `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`. I want to force my main form, which is owned, to appear on the taskbar. So i override `CreateParams` and force it to appear on the taskbar:

```
procedure TfrmMain.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
    inherited;

    Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW; //force owned window to appear in taskbar
end;
```

and we give it a whirl:

[image]

Looking pretty good!

- two taskbar buttons
- the tooltip doesn't pop the wrong owner form forward

except, when i click on the first toolbar button, the wrong form comes up. It shows the modal **frmMain**, rather than the currently modal **frmControlPanel**:

[image]

Presumably because the newly created **frmControlPanel** was PopupParented to **Application.MainForm** rather than **Screen.ActiveForm**. Check in Spy++:

[image]

Yes, the parent is `MainForm.Handle`. This turns out to be because of another bug in the VCL. If the form's `PopupMode` is:

- **pmAuto**
- **pmNone** (if it's a modal form)

the VCL attempts to use `Application.ActiveFormHandle` as the `hWndParent`. Unfortunately it then checks if the modal form's parent is enabled:

```
if (WndParent <> 0) and (
      IsIconic(WndParent) or 
      not IsWindowVisible(WndParent) or
      not IsWindowEnabled(WndParent)) then
```

Of course the modal form's parent is not enabled. If it was, it would not be a modal form. So the VCL falls back to using:

```
WndParent := Application.MainFormHandle;
```

## Manual parenting

This means i probably have to be sure to manually(?) set the popup parenting?

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    frmControlPanel: TfrmControlPanel;
begin
    frmControlPanel := TfrmControlPanel.Create(Application);
    try
        frmControlPanel.PopupParent := Self;
        frmControlPanel.PopupMode := pmExplicit; //Automatically set to pmExplicit when you set PopupParent. But you get the idea.
        frmControlPanel.ShowModal;
    finally
        frmControlPanel.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Except that didn't work either. Clicking the first taskbar button causes the wrong form to activate:

[image]

At this point i'm thoroughly confused. The **parent** of my modal form should be **frmMain**, and it is!:

[image]

### So what now?

I have a sense of what might be going on.

That taskbar button is a representation of **frmMain**. Windows is bringing that for forward.

Except it behaved correctly when **MainFormOnTaskbar** was set to false.

There must be some magic in Delphi VCL that caused correctness before, but gets disabled with **MainFormOnTaskbar := True**, but what is it?

I am not the first person to want a Delphi application to behave nicely with the Windows 95 toolbar. And i've asked this question in the past, but those answers were always geared towards Delphi 5 and it's old central routing window.

I've been told that everything was fixed around Delphi 2007 timeframe.

So what is the correct solution?

### Bonus Reading

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/29/46371.aspx
- [What does WS_EX_APPWINDOW do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204397/what-does-ws-ex-appwindow-do)
- [My detail form is hidden behind main form when calling the TsaveDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502820/my-detail-form-is-hidden-behind-main-form-when-calling-the-tsavedialog)
- [The Oracle at Delphi Blog: PopupMode and PopupParent](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2004/02/10/295)
- [DocWiki: Vcl.Forms.TForm.PopupMode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.PopupMode)
- [DocWiki: Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.PopupParent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.PopupParent)
- [How can I start Delphi application with the hidden main form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441787/how-can-i-start-delphi-application-with-the-hidden-main-form)

Comment: @KenWhite images are not the problem (I think). Main issue with this question is that, unless I spend next hour reading it, I don't think I will be able to tell what is the real question and what is desired behavior.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Yeah. Someone missed the part in the [help] that said "Don't write a book. Your question should be brief, and not require dozens of illustrations." Users of mobile devices (particularly those using a web browser and not the SO app) are going to be really irritated here. I'm tempted to send Ian a bill for data charges.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I edit the question to add a horizontal line to indicate where you can stop reading. Everything after it is *research effort*.

Comment: @IanBoyd: The long and short of it is that VCL was **never** designed for this, so you have to do a LOT of hacking to make it work the way you are asking (if you are even successful). BorCoDero made some pretty bad implementation decisions from day 1 when `ShowMainFormOnTaskbar` was first added, and they kept compounding the problem by tying more and more features to it instead of keeping them separated, all in the name of backwards compatibility with minimal changes to user code, resulting in a messy implementation that does all of the wrong things nowadays. Good luck trying to untangle it!

Comment: @RemyLebeau I remember seeing a QC article that, i thought, asked for `ShowMainFormOnToolbar` to be removed, as it does not do what everyone thinks it does. Was that yours? BorImCoDero....you mean that started to stick!? :)   And, finally, i thought, i really really thought, that Delphi XE6 would finally be Windows 95 compatible :(  I kinda sort hinted to customers that they might be able to have modeless forms now that *'we moved the tool we use to a newer version"*. :(

Comment: The title of the question isn't clear.

Comment: @IanBoyd: IMHO, they should never have introduced `ShowMainFormOnTaskbar` in the first place. They should have instead introduced separate `TApplication.ShowOnTaskbar` and `TForm.ShowOnTaskbar` properties instead, and maybe even a `TForm.ApplicationWindowIsOwner` property. How many times over the years have people asked to hide the `TApplication` window from the taskbar, or add a `TForm` window to the taskbar?  Too many to count.  Those should have been added as separate features. Maybe they can still do that, and deprecate `ShowMainFormOnTaskbar` to set the appropriate properties.

Comment: @Jouan Yeah, you're right, that was pretty bad grammer. I started writing the question yesterday afternoon, and i never re-read the title.

Comment: It depends on whether you want the modeless form to be owned or not. That determines whether you set `WndParent`, or not. If you do set `WndParent` then you need to make it an app window. And then you need to deal with the consequences. You'll have to fix the bug in the hint system.

Comment: Congratulations on the longest question on Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: Might have better luck just writing your own implementation of forms rather than tweaking VCL.

Comment: @JerryDodge [You should see this question of mine from a few years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687903/sql-server-management-studio-import-quietly-ignoring-99-9-of-data); although that was really to prove to people that i'm not crazy. There was also [this question from a couple of weeks ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549816/how-to-simulate-drop-down-form-in-delphi) that i got no end of grief over!

Comment: Here's what I would try: First, don't make your "sacrificial" main form be your main form. Make it be a short-lived form that exists only as long as it takes to log in. Once you're logged in, *then* create the main form. Then you can let the main form be on the taskbar just as Delphi wants it to be, without changing its creation parameters. I also wouldn't make frmMain be modal. Alternatively, if the login form is to continue being the sacrificial main form, then I still wouldn't make frmMain be modal. Instead, I'd make it be a top-level unowned window just like frmModeless.

Comment: You see, I never got as far as the part about the hidden main form. Don't do that. In fact, call Application.CreateForm exactly once. For the real main form. For the modeless form, decide whether you want it to be owned or not. Should all work out swimmingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that the fundamental problem is that your main form is, in the eyes of the VCL, not your main form. Once you fix that, all the problems go away.

You should:

1. Call `Application.CreateForm` exactly once, for the real main form. That is a good rule to follow. Consider the job of `Application.CreateForm` to be to create the main form of your application.
2. Create the login form and set its `WndParent` to `0`. That makes sure it appears on the taskbar. Then show it modally.
3. Create the main form in the usual way by calling `Application.CreateForm`.
4. Set `MainFormOnTaskbar` to be `True`.
5. Set `WndParent` to `0` for the modeless form.

And that's it. Here's a complete example:

**Project1.dpr**

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  uMain in 'uMain.pas' {MainForm},
  uLogin in 'uLogin.pas' {LoginForm},
  uModeless in 'uModeless.pas' {ModelessForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.ShowHint := True;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  with TLoginForm.Create(Application) do begin
    ShowModal;
    Free;
  end;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**uLogin.pas**

```
unit uLogin;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TLoginForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TLoginForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.WndParent := 0;
end;

end.
```

**uLogin.dfm**

```
object LoginForm: TLoginForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'LoginForm'
  ClientHeight = 300
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

**uMain.pas**

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, uModeless;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TModelessForm.Create(Self) do begin
    Show;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**uMain.dfm**

```
object MainForm: TMainForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'MainForm'
  ClientHeight = 300
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 288
    Top = 160
    Width = 75
    Height = 23
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

**uModeless.pas**

```
unit uModeless;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TModelessForm = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TModelessForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.WndParent := 0;
end;

end.
```

**uModeless.dfm**

```
object ModelessForm: TModelessForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'ModelessForm'
  ClientHeight = 300
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  ShowHint = True
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 312
    Top = 160
    Width = 98
    Height = 13
    Hint = 'This is a hint'
    Caption = 'I'#39'm a label with a hint'
  end
end
```

If you'd rather the modeless form was owned by the main form, you can achieve that by replacing `TModelessForm.CreateParams` with:

```
procedure TModelessForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
end;
```

Comment: An issue with that change is that closing the *"main"* form no longer returns you to the *"login"* form. In the revised version the main form closes and the application terminates. I did follow your suggestion of adding (another) fix to `Vcl.Controls.pas` to set the proper parent for the `THintWindow`, and it seemed to work. In general my reason for asking was that i had blindly *assumed* that Delphi had fixed it. For years people were telling me *"stop running an outdated version of Delphi"*. I figured it was all solved, and i was just missing something like `.ShowModless` or something.

Comment: You can sort that out by changing the close action on the main form and showing a new login form, or re-showing the original one. Start from the premise that you make the main form be the VCL main form, and fit around that. Then all will be well.

Comment: Ought, but i don't *wannnaaaa* do that. :)    Then i remember the words from Raymond Chen: [Nobody said programming was going to be easy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/21/483438.aspx).

Comment: Well, you should want to do that. It makes everything easier.

Comment: Can you think of a way to re-show the login form as the `MainForm` has closed? In your example you destroy the login form before getting to the `MainForm` and `Application.Run`. I would need to re-show the login form that was.

Comment: The problem with creating a new one is that it is not the old one. I found the best hack ever. Rather than showing my *"main"* form using `.ShowModal`, i show it using `Application.Run`. That way all the code after the call the `.ShowModal` can continue to run (inside all it's existing `try..finally`), and best of all the user doesn't lose the existing logon form they had.

Answer (score 0):

Great working thanks so much
I use this

```
  Application.Initialize;
 // Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;///*
  Application.CreateForm(TAT_musteriler, AT_dATA);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm4, Form4);
```

....
which form is showing (active) that show on windows task bar if * line active only 1 form showing on taskbar when i hide main form and show other form i cant see at windows task bar